# Module import error in virtualenv but pip list --local shows it

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm wondering about the following importError which I can't get ride off. I have a local virtualenv (venv) in which I've installed multiple modules:

```
(venv) stam@stam:~$ pip list --local

cryptography (1.5.2)
cvxopt (1.1.9)
cycler (0.10.0)
Cython (0.25.1)
matplotlib (1.5.3)
more-itertools (2.2)
ndg-httpsclient (0.4.2)
numpy (1.11.2)
pandas (0.19.0)
paramiko (1.15.2)
Pillow (2.8.1)
pip (8.1.2)
psycopg2 (2.6)
python-apt (0.9.3.12)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
python-debian (0.1.27)
scipy (0.18.1)
setuptools (28.6.1)
simplejson (3.8.2)
urllib3 (1.9.1)
wheel (0.24.0)
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(venv) stam@stam:~$
```

now starting a python interpreter and trying to import cvxopt (note it is in the list above) gives me a importError. Why is this? I'm using the right python version, I work on the venv so everything should work out of the box.

```
(venv) stam@stam:~$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Aug 13 2016, 16:41:35) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cvxopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cvxopt
>>>
```

I'm a bit lost and don't know how exactly I can resolve this issue. It seems the right python version is started, at least the one I've attached to the virtualenv.

**Additional outps asked for in the comments**

```
(venv) stam@stam:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
(venv) stam@stam:~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one Python installation, and that ``pip`` is using one (e.g. Python 3) whereas ``python`` is using another (e.g. Python 2)? Try using ``python -m pip install cvxopt`` and see if helps.

Comment: @DanGittik looks like that is the issue. However, I'm a bit confused. I thought by workon the right venv python is using the right pip, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on whether ``pip`` is installed in your virtual environment - if it's missing, ``pip`` will fall back to the default one. Can you post the results of ``which python``, ``which pip``, and ``ls $(dirname $(which python))``?

Comment: @DanGittik thanks for your help. I've added the additional output except the last one. It was too long to display here

Comment: It seems neither ``python`` nor ``pip`` is from your virtual environment, although you have the ``(venv)`` prefix in your prompt, so you seem to have activated it. Have you moved or renamed its directory?

Comment: @DanGittik No I didnt. That's weird indeed...do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: Try re-activating the virtual environment, e.g. ``source /path/to/venv/bin/activate``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output from `which` it seems clear that your python and pip belong to two different instances. So all libraries you install will be installed for some other python instance.

The acute fix is to force pip to run through your specified interpreter:

```
python -m pip list --local
python -m pip install cvxopt
```